# IoC and the Factory Pattern

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container, factory

If I understand the Factory Pattern correctly, I might have a factory for creating my Repos that implements an interface like this ...

```
public interface IRepoFactory
{
    T Get<T>() where T : IRepo
}
```

And in that factory a call to `RepoFactory.Get<IRepo1>()` will return a newly minted instance of a class implementing IRepo1.

So, in the definition of `RepoFactory` I will create a new instance of the appropriate type...

```
switch(...)
{
    case typeof(IRepo1):
    return new Repo1();        
}
```

Or, I assume, I can define a constructor for `Repofactory` that takes, as parameters, an interface representing all of the possible return types...

```
public RepoFactory(IRepo1 repo1, IRepo2 repo2, ..., IRepoN repoN) : IRepoFactory
```

and let my IoC container do the work of creating the classes.

So, to my question. If I *do* create a constructor as above, doesn't that mean that each time I include `IRepoFactory` as a constructor parameter I will get a new instance of Repo1, Repo2,..., RepoN? Is that a resource heavy process? Is it a wasteful way to do things if, in any given case, I will likely need only a subset of the total number of available repos?

Is there a way of getting the IoC (Unity, in my case) to only create an instance at the time it is needed, a Lazy Loading, if you will? Or am I simply worrying about nothing?

Comment: I haven't used Unity, but Autofac and StructureMap can both inject object factories out of the box. Just make the constructor parameter a func i.e. MyClass(Func<IRepo<MyEntity>> repoFactory). Then, in the class that's taking the dependency, you can say var repo = repoFactory() and you'll get a new instance. Unity may have a similar feature.

Comment: I'll have another rummage through the docs, @Nelson, Ta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood `Factory`. Factory should create instances. That's mean nothing should be in factory constructor beside of Di container or LifeTimeScope.

You can use your own factory or you can use auto generated factory.

I'm not familiar Unity but I checked they have.

```
public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        private readonly Func<IRepo1> _repo1;

        public MyService(Func<IRepo1> repo1)
        {
            _repo1 = repo1;
        }

        public void Method1()
        {

            var myRepo = _repo1();
        }

        public void Method2()
        {
            //Repo1 instance will be different than in Method1
            var myRepo = _repo1();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a container then you can let the container resolve the type of repo when needed.

Here is a rough example of how you can do it. Note you will change the code to suit you specific container and also the assumption here is that you would have also already configured the container to know hot to resolve the types you want.

```
public class DefaultRepoFactory : IRepoFactory {
    IUnityContainer container;

    public DefaultRepoFactory(IUnityContainer container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public T Get<T>() where T : IRepo {        
        return (T)container.Resolve<T>();
    }
}
```

Configuration

```
IUnityContainer myContainer = new UnityContainer();
IRepoFactory myDefaultFactory = new DefaultRepoFactory(myContainer);
myContainer.RegisterInstance<IRepoFactory>(myDefaultFactory);
```

Comment: Isn't it better if we use generic class instead of generic method and register generic factory. Because now in our service we have will `IRepoFactory` but we don't know which repositories will be used. If we change it to generic class it will be like this  `MyService(IRepoFactory<IRepo1> repo1)`

Comment: It'd work but I'd argue that having dependency on IUnityContainer would not be a good choice, you tightly couple Factory with unity container.